# Changing Id of nodes in different controllers

Tags: css, javafx-8

I have this code in Application class

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource(CONSTANTS.DESIGN_CSS.directory).toExternalForm());
```

and this CSS file

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";

#mainList .list-cell {
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-font-size: 24px;
    -fx-text-fill: linear-gradient( from 0.0% 0.0% to 0.0% 50.0%, reflect, rgba(255,0,0,0.28) 0.0, rgba(102,243,255,0.58) 50.0, rgba(179,179,179,0.45) 70.0, rgba(179,179,179,0.45) 100.0);
}
#mainList .list-cell:hover {
    -fx-text-fill:linear-gradient( from 0.0% 0.0% to 100.0% 100.0%, reflect, rgb(255,255,255) 0.0, rgb(255,255,77) 100.0);
}

#stoperButton .button { 
    -fx-background-color:  linear-gradient( from 50.0% 100.0% to 100.0% 100.0%, rgb(0,0,0) 0.0, rgb(255,255,255) 100.0);
}

#stoperButton .button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #9ACD32;
}
```

In the first controller that loads I can easly do this and it works:

```
listView.setId("mainList");
```

but this(in different controller) gets me no error but no effect:

```
buttSTOP.setId("stoperButton");
```

is it has something to do with changing the root of the scene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector

```
#stoperButton .button { ... }
```

matches a node that has the style class "button" and is a descendent of a node with css id "stoperButton".

I think what you want is just

```
#stoperButton {
    -fx-background-color:  linear-gradient( from 50.0% 100.0% to 100.0% 100.0%, rgb(0,0,0) 0.0, rgb(255,255,255) 100.0);
}

#stoperButton:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #9ACD32;
}
```

Comment: Yes it work. I just dont understand why its a different analogy to `#mainList .list-cell:hover{...` ??

Comment: There are no buttons inside your `stoperButton`, so `#stoperButton .button` doesn't match anything. On the other hand, `ListView`s contain `ListCell`s, so `#mainList .list-cell` matches all the list cells inside `mainList` (i.e. you are applying the style to the individual list cells).